# Converting Varchar() to Date?

Tags: t-sql

Querying a table and one of the filters I want to use is a date between i.e. 02/08/19 and 02/10/19. For whatever reason the table I was working with for this filter has a Varchar(50) column made to look like a DateTime 120 style (yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss.fff). How do I convert this to a Date (mm/dd/yy) format? If it were a real DateTime I would typically just cast it As Date.

So far I've tried:

```
select convert(varchar(50), a.alpha, 1), a.bravo, sum(a.charlie)
from table a
where convert(varchar(50), a.alpha, 1) between '02/08/19' and '02/10/19'
group by convert(varchar(50), a.alpha, 1), a.bravo
order by sum(a.charlie)
```

This doesn't seem to pull any records. I then switched it to 120 instead of 1 and switched the filters to '2019-02-08 00:00:00.000' and '2019-02-10 00:00:00.000' and it worked, but this isn't the format I need. I tried casting these converts as date i.e. cast(convert(varchar(50), a.alpha, 1) as date) and that didn't work either.

What should I do now?

Thanks,

Comment: If `a.alpha` is already a `varchar(50)`, why are you converting it to `varchar`? you should be converting it to `date`. Also, when dealing with string representations of date, it's best to work with ISO8601 format (`yyyyddmm` / `yyyy-dd-mm`* ), as SQL Server will always handle it correctly (* except when working with the `datetime` data type, the second format will be culture specific - one more reason to prefer `datetime2` over `datetime`).

Comment: Dates have *no* format, they are binary values just like integers, doubles and `numeric`. *Don't* store dates as strings. You should fix the table design to use `date` instead. You can use [PARSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)  to parse the US-specific format to a date eg `PARSE(a.alpha AS date USING 'en-US')`

Comment: BTW that US-only format *can't* be sorted. Any indexes that cover that text field will be useless for date calculations and searches. And using a two-digit year is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert a varchar to a varchar while you should do it to a date. Even in that case, conversion will fail so you can do the conversion twice to let it filter with no error. This should work for you:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CONVERT(date, a.alpha),1), a.bravo, sum(a.charlie)
FROM table a
WHERE CONVERT(CONVERT(date, a.alpha),1) BETWEEN '02/08/19' and '02/10/19'
GROUP BY convert(convert(date, a.alpha),1) , a.bravo
ORDER BY sum(a.charlie)
```